# Are edits to remove political view allowed?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my The Workplace Stack Exchange post: [Am I wrong to tell my coworkers my favorite presidential candidate?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64540/am-i-wrong-to-tell-my-coworkers-my-favorite-presidential-candidate)

So originally I was asking about Trump as my political candidate, and I know a lot of people get upset by him.  No one really seemed to care what I was actually asking and just got upset over the fact that I was talking about Trump.  I followed up with more of a parody, and the result was the same.  Now my actual question has been censored, all because I had a serious question about my political views.  Is this allowed just because I was talking about Trump?

Comment: And you think political views are on-topic on The Workplace...why?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'd like to direct you to my comments for enderland's answer... Really, read the question.  It's NOT ABOUT ME EXPLAINING MY POLITICAL VIEWS, I AM ASKING IF IT'S OK FOR THE ACTUAL WORKPLACE.  As in that thing you're suppose to do during the day and get paid for as oppose to answering questions that amount to nothing.

Comment: @Walle if your goal is to ask if "its ok" then the specifics of who your favorite candidate is doesn't matter. Considering the entire point of this meta question is "why did you censor my political candidate" it seems pretty clear your primary interest in posting your question was to talk about Trump -- not get an actual answer to your question.

Comment: -_- you're making about this much sense http://www.razerzone.com/breadwinner.  The reason I specify Trump is because people do often have a much stronger bias against him than other candidates.  You know IT'S POSSIBLE PEOPLE WOULDN'T GET UPSET OVER HILLARY, OR LINCOLN CHAFFEY, OR LITTLE MARCO RUBIO. But since there's a very strong bias against Trump, you know, maybe people would think that matters?

Comment: related: [Why is Stack Exchange so hard to troll](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0jCv.png)

Comment: Rarely have to say this on meta, but voted to close. Your question seems to be "Is it okay to do X because of reason Y?" when neither X nor Y actually happened. On the off-chance that this isn't some poor attempt at trolling, consider some self-reflection, assuming that your political views don't prevent such a radical action.

Comment: @Lilienthal my palm has transcended my face and gone into the cosmos now.

Comment: On a very likely related note, Happy April Fool's Day.

Comment: So I'm confused, why is his question an issue?  Like what rules does he break in saying "Trump"?  There is a bias against him, I'll be honest, I don't like Trump, and I don't like any other candidate and it's pretty clear the internet will have a civil conversation about any other candidate, but the moment it's Trump, it's guns (down votes and edits) a-blazing.

Comment: @keshlam but should answers really impact the question? I'm thinking that answers could potentially be different based on candidates because they're human, and everyone has opinions, that's pretty clear on other stackexchanges like SO where 80% of questions involving windows have to specify they don't want a "Windows sucks" answer.  Specifying these things can bring about different emotions, particularly in the OP's original question, Trump is controversial, other candidates, not really, his coworkers might be fine with hearing about others for all we know. Just trying to keep this unbias.

Comment: Yeah I don't think anyone wants a bias answer.  I'm just playing devil's advocate in saying "maybe if it weren't about Trump, it have been received more positively"

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer was Trump specific, because Trump is ... well ... different. If he had said he had a scary psychopath costume for Halloween, or favorite cartoon character, that would modify the answer. Trump is a combination of it all: political, cartoon character and scary psychopath.

Comment: I would not want to close this question as it is such a good example of such a bad example.

Comment: When do we vote for moderators? I want to nominate @Walle. He promises to build a wall between the trolls and the good users!

Answer (score 8):

If your goal is for the question to be reopened and/or received well I suggest reading the [what types of questions to avoid asking](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section of the help center.

That entire page of the help center is relevant here. I was going to quote relevant excerpts but your question pretty much fails every *single* criteria listed in the help center.

Of course your comment (which I deleted, among others) about another president probably did not do much to convince me that you are asking a serious question. Additionally, there is absolutely *no* reason why your post required the commentary it did. Any answer about Trump would be the same about any other candidate.

Comment: Seriously, does anyone on stackexchange actually read the questions? I'm not asking to reopen my question.  Read the question please.  I am asking if it's ok for those edits because of people's political views don't align. But same thing is happening here.  Talk about abuse of power...

Comment: @Walle if you want to argue politics with people, you will find Stack Exchange is not the place for you.

Answer (score 2):

> Are bias edits due to political view allowed?

Yes.  Particularly when it results in a question and answers that are more generally applicable.